# PRISMA: Getting type error on where clause in update method

Tags: orm, prisma

Have a specific Prisma ORM library error that I need help with.

I have created a migration and pushed it to a postgres db.

I have generated the client model for Prisma and am able to findAll and insert data using the create method.

Where I am having trouble is the update method.

Here's my code

```
app.post("/articles/:title", async (req: Request, res: Response) => {
  const article = await prisma.article.update({
    where: { title: req.params.title },
    data: { title: req.body.title, content: req.body.content },
  })
  res.send('The article was posted sucessfully.' + article)
})
```

I am getting the following error which makes me think that the client is not finding a type 'title' when using the where argument.

app.ts:65:14 - error TS2322: Type '{ title: string; }' is not assignable to type 'ArticleWhereUniqueInput'.
Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'title' does not exist in type 'ArticleWhereUniqueInput'.

65     where: { title: req.params.title },
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

node_modules/.prisma/client/index.d.ts:784:3
784   where: ArticleWhereUniqueInput
~~~~~
The expected type comes from property 'where' which is declared here on type 'Subset<ArticleUpdateArgs, ArticleUpdateArgs>'

Has anyone else had this issue?
I tried to introspect the database just to make sure the database was captured exactly as is, with title and content fields and then generated the client again.

Many thanks
James

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to upsert new record in Prisma without an ID?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55404678/how-to-upsert-new-record-in-prisma-without-an-id)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found the answer: [Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55404678/how-to-upsert-new-record-in-prisma-without-an-id) answer was a response from [Antonie](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4909450/antoine)

The fields in

- where

needs to be unique.

If you can make some field, let's say date @unique (date: DateTime! @unique), and use that for your where in the upsert, I think it would work (tested on my local).

Answer (score 0):

Use `.(find/update/delete)Many()` if you are trying to query with multi values.